# Can I apply CSS to a <div>'s background-image?

Tags: html, css

So I'm just having some fun with HTML and CSS, and I was trying to overlay some text over an image.

The way I was taught was to give the image a div all for itself, and set it as the background image. Then you could type right over it.

However, I want the background-image of the div to comply to some CSS I already wrote, telling the image to scale to the page's width.

Is there a way of applying CSS to the 's background image? Or should I choose another route?

Thanks in advance,

Rain

Code:

```css
  body {
     background-color: #d0d0d5;
    }
    
    
    #pageWrapper {
     margin-left: -10px;
     margin-top: -15px;
     margin-right: -200px;
     background-color: #9b9a9d;
     height: 1500px;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    #header {
     font-family: Lato; 
     font-weight: bold;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     height: 70px;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #E8E8F0;
    }
    
     .links {
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
     }
    
     .linkLeft {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-right: 20px;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }
    
     .linkRight {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }
    
     #link5 {
      padding-right: 40px;
    
     }
    
    #imageWrapper {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
     }
     
     
     #jumbotron {
         max-width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
         background-image: url(img/Canadian-Rockies-Mountains.jpg);
         
     }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=en>

 <head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="pageWrapper">
   
   <div id="header">
    <ul class="links"><li><a href="#" class="linkLeft">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkLeft">Browse</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight" id="link5">Help</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight">Log In</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight">Sign Up</a></li></ul>

   </div> <!--header END-->

   <div id="imageWrapper">
    <!--<div id="imageText">
     <h1>Discover the Canadian Rockies.</h1>
     <p>Book a trip to Canada today, guy.</p>
    </div>-->
    <div id="jumbotron"></div>
    <!--Original code used to place image before I wanted text overlay follows-->
    <!--<img id="jumbotron"src="img/Canadian-Rockies-Mountains.jpg" />-->
   </div>

  </div> <!--pageWrapper END-->
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add some code, it will be easier to help you. you have a dedicated button (code snippet)

Comment: There are specific CSS styles (`background-position`, `background-size`, etc.) that apply here. Styles intended for `img` tags, etc. will be of no help.

Comment: I would upload your css, and html, and I would rephrase how you start your question "Yo" isn't very professional.

Comment: `div { background-size: cover }` the size can basically be ANY css unit. px, pt, %, etc...

Comment: Sorry for being unprofessional :/ code coming up.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll test it at some stage, consider it solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

These properties (like `background-size`) will be in relation to the div who has the `background-image` set. To make the div itself fill its parent, set `width: 100%` in the div's class

Answer (score 0):

simple example to apply `css` for image inside div

### CSS

```
   .header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
}
```

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUx7U/114/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div  {
    background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question properly, `background-size: cover` will force the image to expand the way you want. I've modified your code, is this the effect you're looking for?

```css
  body {
     background-color: #d0d0d5;
    }
    
    
    #pageWrapper {
     margin-left: -10px;
     margin-top: -15px;
     margin-right: -200px;
     background-color: #9b9a9d;
     height: 1500px;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    #header {
     font-family: Lato; 
     font-weight: bold;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     height: 70px;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #E8E8F0;
    }
    
     .links {
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
     }
    
     .linkLeft {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-right: 20px;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }
    
     .linkRight {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
     }
    
     #link5 {
      padding-right: 40px;
    
     }
    
    #imageWrapper {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300);
background-size: cover;
height: 200px;
     }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=en>

 <head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="pageWrapper">
   
   <div id="header">
    <ul class="links"><li><a href="#" class="linkLeft">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkLeft">Browse</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight" id="link5">Help</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight">Log In</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="linkRight">Sign Up</a></li></ul>

   </div> <!--header END-->

   <div id="imageWrapper">
    <div id="imageText">
     <h1>Discover the Canadian Rockies.</h1>
     <p>Book a trip to Canada today, guy.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div> <!--pageWrapper END-->
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you cover a complete screen and make it adapt to screen size.

```
html, body {
        position:relative;
        height: 100%;
        background:url('yoururl')no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover; 
    }
```